# fetch correct number SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table:

```
id      Number
--------------------
1   61326085092
2   161569087548
3   169193968080
4   208082024640
5   230160816344
6   218557943068
```

I am declaring a float variable:

```
DECLARE @varible AS FLOAT
```

when I set a variable with the result of a query to the table described:

```
SELECT @variable  =  Number FROM @TableR where ID =  1;
```

I am getting:
variable: 6.13261e+010

So this is annoying because As I am computing with big values, I am losing some numbers...
How do I fetch the result as it is `61326085092`, not  `6.13261e+010` 
Could this be a varchar-float convertion error?

so for example:

```
DECLARE @var AS FLOAT
set @var = 6.13261e+010 * 6.13261e+010
PRINT LTRIM(STR(@var,32,15))

set @var = 61326085092 * 61326085092
PRINT  LTRIM(STR(@var,32,15))
```

results:

```
3760890541210000200000.000000000
3760888712711224400000.000000000
```

very different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the precision, eg: [see here](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/80603-formatting-float-varchar-but-not-scientific-notation)

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), CAST(@testFloat AS decimal(38,2)))
```

or

```
SELECT STR(@testFloat, 38, 2)
```

Comment: But if I want to assign the select result to a float var??

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you used BigInt? BTW, what's the data type of your 'Number' field?

Comment: The data type is FLOAT, I am using float because later I will use some sqrt and pow...

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to display the query results in?  It looks to me that the resultset itself is correctly returning a float amount, but whatever is formatting / displaying the results is converting it to scientific notation - the method you should use to avoid this depends on what you are using (e.g. C#?)

Comment: I have posted an example, The error comes later when doing multiplication or sqrt of some numbers `DECLARE @var AS FLOAT
set @var = 6.13261e+010 * 6.13261e+010
PRINT LTRIM(STR(@var,32,15))

set @var = 61326085092 * 61326085092
PRINT  LTRIM(STR(@var,32,15))` resulting `3760890541210000200000.000000000    
3760888712711224400000.000000000`

Answer (score 0):

You're not losing numbers, rather the software that is displaying the number is formatting it in a shortened version. Are you using Query Analyzer? If you want to force it to be displayed with all the numbers then you should cast it to a string.

```
DECLARE @varible AS FLOAT
SELECT @variable  =  Number FROM @TableR where ID =  1;
print cast(@variable as varchar)
```